# Google map generating incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a program that takes in a zip code and makes a google map. The `div` that the map is set to`hidden` until the map is made. Once the map is made the `div` is set to `display : block`. The problem is that the first time the map is generated (and only the first time) it looks like this:
[image]

Once I hit the find a store button again it looks like this:

[image]

I have already tried to make a initial call to the map method (which I kept hidden until a real call is made) but this does not fix the issue. I don't want to show all my code (there is a lot) but here is how I make the map.

```
<div id = "map_canvas" style = " height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>

//Creates a new center location for the google map
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

//The options for the google map
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    maxZoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

//Creates the new map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

Also note that both images below have the correct markers in the correct place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a common problem. you need to trigger a map redraw after changing the container. most of the time this is caused by showing/hiding the div.

in v3 it's:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

in v2 it's:

```
map.checkResize()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you initialize the map, it is completely zoomed out, which brings out the single 250x250 tile that google uses.

Comment: Why would it be zoomed out though? I have a zoom and max zoom set

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that possibly an error is occurring on your first "Find Store" button click that might prevent the map creation code from being reached and executing properly.

Comment: I thought so to, but if it was an issue with the button, then wouldn't I have issues with it every other time, and not just the initial call?