# Google Map is not shown correctly inside jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map inside a jquery tab. The problem is that when I switch to the tab that contains map, my map is shown incorrectly. look at the picture:

[image]

After resizing window, map renders ok. Any idea?

Comment: Duplicated post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518225/google-map-generating-incorrectly

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455536/google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs-map-not-resizing

Comment: Not much we can do with a screenshot other than guess that you map div doesn't have a size. Please show us your code if you want a more qualified answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')